# Run time error 13 on deleting multiple rows in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have a macro which is as follows:

```
Dim oval

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Value = Null Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
oval = Target.Value
MsgBox Target.Count

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

When I run the following macro and when I select multiple rows and then delete it, it throws the error below. It only happens for multiple rows. I also tried to add a condition which says If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub and that didn't seem to fix it as well.

```
Microsoft Visual Basic

Run-time error '13':

Type mismatch
```

Comment: Try replacing `Null` with `vbNullString`

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target.Value is an array when you select multiple cells, so you can't check it's "value" To check the value of the first item you could do something like (for testing):

```
Debug.Print Target.Value()(1,1)
```

You can check this with IsArray, and if you want to just end if it's an array then

```
If IsArray(Target.Value) Then Exit Sub
```

It looks like you want the count though, so maybe something like:

```
Dim oval

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox Target.Count
Else
    If Target.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    oval = Target.Value
    MsgBox Target.Count
End If
End Sub
```

although I'm sure you want to do something with oval ... I'll leave that up to you though.

Comment: Not sure what the intent of his code is but simply `If Target.Count > 1...` might do the trick, just a little bit more simply.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code from `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event to `Worksheet_Change` event.

Also, multiple cells will be only once you delete multiple cells, so there's no need for the second `If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub`. Unless you don't want `oval` to have an "empty" value.

**Code**

```
Dim oval

Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

' this line might be redundant
'If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False    
oval = Target.Value    

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I had to use both the SelectionChange and the Change events but this was a good solution as well. Thanks.